# angularjs and ASP.NET MVC : best strategy for clientside models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently looking into client side model binding to HTML templates especially with angularjs. I was wondering what the best strategy is for retrieving clientside viewmodels from the server, e.g. a viewmodel containing not only the data for editing but also the data for select lists or drop down lists etc..

As I see it , one has several options

1. retrieve one viewmodel from the server using e.g. web api, containing ALL the data needed for the view model
2. render a client side viewmodel to javascript inside the server side html
3. retrieve data for the viewmodel using multiple web api calls, e.g one for the main data to be edited, and one for each additional data (select lists)

I didn't encounter many examples for option 1 as it seems that web api is used mostly for crud operations returning specific data for one type of object e.g. Person or Order

option 2 conforms to the practice of server side view models with asp.net mvc but I have not seen many examples using this technique in combination with angularjs

option 3 looks clean if one considers seperation of concerns, but has the disadvantage of multiple smaller ajax requests.

Could you share your thoughts and experiences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with st. never and have definitely used option #3 and I think combining $resource and Web API would be a perfect RAD combination. However, I've also worked on very complex screens where I've wanted sub-second response times so I've resorted to optimise the entire development 'column' - I develop using SQL Server as my backend database so I've used it's native support for XML to return structured XML from a stored procedure which I then serialise into a .Net Model (POCO) which I then pass to a Json serialiser for transfer to the browser. I might have some extra business processing to perform against the POCO but this still leads to a very simple code structure to transfer a fairly complex structure of data. Typically it's also very fast because I've made one call to the database and monitoring and optimising one stored procedure is very simple.

Comment: Why not use something like Dapper to serialize to POCOs, and skip the XML steps? We're transitioning our .Net app from Backbone / homegrown JS to an Angular solution with Web API. It would be interesting to hear your experiences with Angular and how you've integrated it with .Net

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use option #3. The app would make requests to "prepare the editor", such as populating dropdown lists, and requests to fetch the data you want to edit (or, if you are creating a new object, any default initial values). I think this separates concerns better than option #1, which ties together "model" data and "support" data.

But as you pointed out, this does make extra calls, and, if they are very numerous, can noticeably slow down the page. (or increase complexity; on a big form with lots of dependent fields, ordering may become important).

What I usually do is have the server provide a "combined" api (e.g. `/editor/prepare-all`) while also providing  small pieces (e.g. `/editor/prepare-dropdown-1`, `/editor/prepare-dropdown-2`). When your editor loads, you use the combined one; if there are dependencies between fields, you can request only the data for the dependent fields (e.g. `/editor/prepare-dropdown-2?dropdown1-value=123`). I believe this has little impact on the server's complexity.